# Erro ao adicionar dependências no maven

Tags: java, maven

Quando adiciono os imports solicitados para as classes

```
 KeycloakAuthenticationToken keycloakAuthenticationToken = (KeycloakAuthenticationToken) principals;
         AccessToken accessToken = keycloakAuthenticationToken.getAccount().getKeycloakSecurityContext().getToken();
```

Aparece o seguinte erro no Package

```
The type org.springframework.security.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationToken cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

Ja tentei solucionar realizando maven update, apagando o diretorio dentro de .m2 e recriando com um update, ja realizei um project -> clean, tudo sem sucesso.

E assim esta o meu .m2

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você poderia postar seu pom.xml para visualizarmos. Para isso, edite a pergunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certifique que esteja adicionado ao pom esta dependência.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.2</version>
 </dependency>
```

Se já estiver, tente buscar uma versão mais nova em
[Maven Repository Spring Security Core](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-core)

Se estiver utilizando spring-boot, veja se está adicionado:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
```